# AES-GCM with the Kernel Crypto API from Userspace

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, userspace

I am trying to use the kernel crypto API to communicate with a hardware accelerator from userspace.
I use `af_alg` for the communication with the kernel. I can use the API for hashing or "normal" symmetric encryption but I can not get it to work with an aead algorithm. The drivers are registered under `/proc/crypto`.
I follow the kernel documentation for the userspace interface to prepare the message but I get the same error *Invalig Argument* every time.

```
#ifndef AF_ALG
#define AF_ALG 38
#endif
#ifndef SOL_ALG
#define SOL_ALG 279
#endif

int main(void)
{
 int openfd;
 int tfmfd;

 char key [16] = "SecretKeyforAES!";
 char initVector[12] = "123456789012";
 //initiaze vector, in/out vector and buffer
 struct af_alg_iv *iv;
 struct iovec iov;
 char buf[64];
 //size of the aad and the auth tag
 uint32_t aadSize = 8;
 uint32_t taglen = 12;

 //define algorithm used for cryptography
 struct sockaddr_alg sa = {
        .salg_family = AF_ALG,
        .salg_type = "aead",
        .salg_name = "gcm(aes)"
 };
 //create and bind socket
 tfmfd = socket(AF_ALG, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
 printf("open socket\n");
 int bindvalue = bind(tfmfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa));
 if(bindvalue != 0){
        perror("send != 0");
 }
 assert(bindvalue == 0);

 printf("socket bound\n");

//set socket options: key, AEAD Authentication size
 setsockopt(tfmfd, SOL_ALG, ALG_SET_KEY, key, 16);
 int setTag = setsockopt(tfmfd, SOL_ALG, ALG_SET_AEAD_AUTHSIZE, NULL, taglen);
 assert(setTag >= 0);
 printf("set socket options\n");
 //accept connection
 openfd = accept(tfmfd, NULL, 0);

//check errors with the connections
 assert(tfmfd > 0);
 assert(openfd > 0);

 //Prepare Message
 struct msghdr msg = { 0 };
 struct cmsghdr *cmsg = NULL;
 char cbuf[128] = {0};

 msg.msg_control = cbuf;
 msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(cbuf);
 msg.msg_iovlen = 0;
 msg.msg_iov = NULL;

 //set the Headervalues for the  Operation
 cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
 assert(cmsg != NULL);
 cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_ALG;
 cmsg->cmsg_type = ALG_SET_OP;
 cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(uint32_t)));
 *(__u32 *) CMSG_DATA(cmsg) = ALG_OP_ENCRYPT;

 //set headervalues for IV
 cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmsg);
 assert(cmsg != NULL);
 cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_ALG;
 cmsg->cmsg_type = ALG_SET_IV;
 cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(initVector))); //iv_msg_size

 //set value for iv
 iv = (void *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
 iv->ivlen = 12;
 memcpy(iv->iv, initVector, 12);

 //set headervalues for aad
 uint32_t *assoclen = NULL;
 cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmsg);
 assert(cmsg != NULL);
 cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_ALG;
 cmsg->cmsg_type = ALG_SET_AEAD_ASSOCLEN;
 cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(*assoclen));
 assoclen = (void *) CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
 *assoclen = (uint32_t)aadSize;
 printf("Header values set\n");

 //send initial message
 int send = sendmsg(openfd, &msg, MSG_MORE);
 if(send < 0){
        perror("send < 0");  //This is where the error occures
 }
 assert(send > 0); //This assertion fails following the error above
 printf("Send initial Message...\n");
```

Following the kernel doc I prepared the initial message with the algorithm, iv and length of aad information.
I set the taglen and mode with *setsockopt* as well. I read the man pages of `msghdr`, `cmsg` and `sendmsg` but did not find my error.

EDIT:

- Added a check for binding failure but check exits with 0 -> no error

Comment: Add a check for bind failing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not quite correct in counting `cmsg_len`.

For the first value that's correct though `CMSG_LEN(CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(uint32_t)))` reflects `ALG_SET_OP`.

But not `CMSG_LEN(CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(initVector))); //iv_msg_size` where the data is `iv = (void *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);` -> `struct af_alg_iv *iv;`.
Thus it should be`CMSG_LEN(sizeof(struct af_alg_iv) + sizeof(initVector))`.

Also, `char cbuf[128] = {0};` must consist the total size of ancillary data, what is `char cbuf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(uint32_t)) + CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(struct af_alg_iv) + sizeof(initVector))] = {0}`

Answer (score 0):

The two places where you set `cmsg_len` should not include a call to the `CMSG_SPACE()` macro, since that one will extend the message length with `sizeof(struct cmsghdr)`.